# Call javascript in a button

Tags: javascript, html, button

How to call a javascript in a html button. Button is not working EDITED

Please take a look at jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/winresh24/Sq7hg/341/

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it

function myFunction{

html2canvas([document.getElementById('mydiv')], {

    onrendered: function (canvas) {

        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');


        var image = new Image();
        image.src = data;
        document.getElementById('image').appendChild(image);

}
});
```

}

Comment: Might help if you actually had a `button` somewhere in your example.

Comment: sir please check my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/winresh24/Sq7hg/344/ thanks

Comment: I edited the code above and add the html plss help thanks

Comment: Your function syntax is not correct, whatever errors you might have.  Your error console would have told you that.  `function myFunction() {`

Comment: thanks for the response sir..I'm doing it in php and I couldn't identified the error..please help me sir..I badly need this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you are doing in PHP or not -- by the time it hits the browser it is nothing but an HTML document... you can use the `view source` option of your browser to see what is sent down.  And the error console of your browser is **always** the first place to look.

Comment: Why I'm having this error sir Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined ....Sorry sir I'm a newbie. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onlick="javascript:alert('do something here')"` on a button.

Full code will look like this:

```
<button onlick="javascript:alert('do something here')">Click Me!</button>
```

At the time of answering, you did not have any function, but as Jason suggested, you should do that.

you can also use `onclick="myFunction()"`;

I've edited your jsfiddle. Its working now.

Check it out at <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/Sq7hg/345/</kbd>

Also, You'll need to define the function before you call it.

Mark my answer as answer If I helped you ;)

Comment: It's not working sir. Why is that? Please help Thanks.

Comment: @winresh24, there were some errors in your fiddle. I've fixed it for you. Please mark my answer as answer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer..Do you know how to change the image when the button click? Because in the current code when you click the button continuously the image multiply. What I what to happen is that when I click the button the image in the div just change. Is that possible. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: what is the src of the image that you want?

Comment: I have multiple image in the radio button so when the button click as you do in your code the image add and add. what I want to happen is when the button was click the image that appear was changing. Can you help me with this...Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

put your js into a function, and then modify your html to something like this:

```
<button onclick="your_function"></button>
```

Comment: take look sir the js fiddle nothing happen when I put that button http://jsfiddle.net/winresh24/Sq7hg/344/